# Stackdriver Logging | Missing TraceId and SpanId

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud

I am trying to integrate SpringBootApplication(microservice) with StackdriverLogging by using **spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging**. I am able to see the logs in GCP but in the logs traceId and SpanId is missing.For this I tried to use Spring-cloud-sleuth also, but as I am using apache kafka in my microservice  sleuth is not working properly.
Can anyone help me how Can I add traceId and SpanId information in logs??

**POM.xml Configuration :**

```
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    <dependencyManagement>
          <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
             </dependency>
          </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**logback.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
     <include resource="org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/logging/logback-json-appender.xml" />
    <appender name="CONSOLE_JSON"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
       <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="org.springframework.cloud.gcp.logging.StackdriverJsonLayout">
                <includeTraceId>true</includeTraceId>
                <includeSpanId>true</includeSpanId>
                <includeThreadName>false</includeThreadName>
            </layout>
       </encoder>
    </appender> 
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_JSON" />
    </logger>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_JSON" />
    </root> 

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Sleuth doesn’t send the trace data for every single request. You probably don’t want to trace every single request either. The trace sampling rate can be adjusted by configuring the spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage property. For more details please refer to "Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Sleuth" in this [link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/distributed-tracing-spring-boot-microservices-with-stackdriver-trace-7fe42c6de3f3) and have a look to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5d_dy7RVcpE).